# Custom Icon for individual cluster icon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I want to set a custom icon for a cluster. 
My requirement are as following:

I have many marker...grouped in a cluster, and I want that the icon 
shown corresponds to the icon of the marker that have the date more 
recent. (marker.date)

Any hints o suggest?

Answer (score 0):

[MarkerClusterer for Google Maps v3](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html) has `setCalculator(calculator:function(Array|number))` function, which can be used to override label set on `MarkerClusterer`:

```
var calc = function(markers, numStyles) {
    var maxDate = new Date('01-01-1970');
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var currentDate = new Date(markers[i].date);
        if (maxDate < currentDate){
            maxDate = currentDate;
        }
  }
  return {text: maxDate.getDate()  + "-" + (maxDate.getMonth()+1) + "-" + maxDate.getFullYear(), index: 4};
}

markerCluster.setCalculator(calc);
```

Assumption is that your `Marker` has `date` custom field:

```
var clusterMarkers = [
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.381059,13.504026),
        map: gm_map,
        title:"P1220214 1.JPG",
        date: '2015-10-10'
    }),
.....
];
```

Notes:

- Proper error handling (when casting from `string` to `Date`) should
  be added
- Calculator `index` value is set  to 4, so it can show entire date
  (eg. 2015-12-12). If you change it to smaller value, date label gets
  cut off.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RGS5b/181/